# ZooKeeper in production on WIndows

Tags: java, groovy, apache-zookeeper

Currently, using ZooKeeper on Linux for our initial needs.  Code base is all Java/Groovy.  Later on, will need to support Windows.  However, the ZooKeeper docs [supported platforms](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.5/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_supportedPlatforms) lists only 'development' support for Windows 32:

```
Win32 is supported as a development platform only for both server and client.
```

Are people running ZK successfully in production on windows?  Any issues?

Also, what about 64-bit Windows?  Is anyone doing that and can you share any experience?

Comment: At the risk of seeming flippant, why would you do that to yourself?  Are you actually considering deploying ZK servers on windows in production or are you only talking about ZK clients running on windows systems?

Comment: Not trying to be flippant here myself :), but I don't understand your question.  I certainly didn't generate the need to support Windows, that comes from the lots of folks who do, and we want to be able to support them.  What I have read says that it is only testing/qa that causes the lack of support, so I was wondering if people had taken a chance, and if so, what their experience was.

Comment: Just because your end user runs on windows, what does that have to do with your ZooKeeper server?  What is your use case?

Comment: When you sell a product that depends on zookeeper, and the customers that buy your product want to deploy your product on thier infrastructure, and their entire infrastructure is windows based, it becomes a difficult problem. Especially when the product (and zookeeper) is "write once, run anywhere" java!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone else I work with pointed me to [upcoming support for windows 64-bit](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-1635)

As I neither want nor need to get into a Unix/Windows platform war, I am accepting this for the answer.

Comment: Title of the given resource has changed to _ZooKeeper C client doesn't compile on 64 bit Windows_, so it's not good reference any more.